# paper.js clear raster image and load new one

Tags: javascript, paperjs

First time using `paper.js` and trying to allow the user to free hand draw a line over a raster image. The image loads OK but none of the Mouse events fire.

I initialize the canvas like this (image loads OK):

```
function initCanvas() {

    // Init paper
    $canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

    paper.install(window);
    paper.setup($canvas);

    loadImage('http://project.com/img/image1.jpg', 'init');

}
```

I load my image like this:

```
function loadImage($url, $type = 'load') {

    var $width, $height;

    var $image = new Image();
    $image.src = $url;

    $image.onload = function (imageEvent) {

        var $size = resizeImage($image);
        $width = $size.width;
        $height = $size.height;

        $($canvas).hide();

        if ($type == 'load') {
            // paper.project.clear();
            paper.project.activeLayer.removeChildren();
            paper.view.draw();
        }

        $raster = new paper.Raster({
            source: $image.src,
            position: view.center,
        });

        if ($image.width > $image.height) {
            $raster.rotate(90);
            $width = $size.height;
            $height = $size.width;
        }

        paper.view.viewSize = new Size($width, $height);
        $raster.fitBounds(paper.view.bounds);

        $canvas.width = $width;
        $canvas.height = $height;

        saveImage();

        $($canvas).fadeIn('slow');

    };

}
```

When I change the image, I may pass a img url like this:

```
 loadImage('http://project.com/img/image.jpg', 'load');
```

Or load a new image via a file reader like this:

```
function loadFileReaderToCanvas() {

    // Read in file
    var fileElement = document.getElementById('photo');
    var file = fileElement.files[0];
    var filterType = /^(?:image\/jpg|image\/jpeg|image\/png)$/i;

    // Ensure it's an image
    if (!filterType.test(file.type)) {
        addFileError("Please only select images in JPG, JPEG or PNG-format");
        return;
    }

    // Load the image
    $reader = new FileReader();

    $reader.onload = function (readerEvent) {
        loadImage(readerEvent.target.result, 'load');
    };

    $reader.readAsDataURL(file);

}
```

The first image loads OK.

The file reader image loads OK (url is a B64 src) and replaces the one on the canvas.

But if I clear the file input, and want to load the default image using its address src (`http://project.com/img/default.jpg`) the image will not load and the canvas remains blank. What did I miss? Thanks

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in a fiddle or something like that so we can help you better ?